# PHP session changing after a new window returns to my site from third party site

Tags: javascript, php, session, session-cookies

I have a PHP website `www.example.com` which has a button opening a new window with JS. It then loads a unique url to `www.thirdpartywebsite.com` via AJAX and sets the window's url:

```
var newWindow = window.open("", "_blank", "scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes");
ajax("www.example.com/get-url",
{
    data: someData,
    success: function(response)
    {
        newWindow.location = response.url;
        // something like www.thirdpartywebsite.com/catalog/12345xyz
    }
});
```

Backend PHP code for `www.example.com/get-url` simply makes a curl request to `www.thirdpartywebsite.com` for the unique url and then returns it.

The returned third party site url is a page showing a catalog of items. Each item has a button redirecting the user back to my site with the item data in POST. The url for that is `www.example.com/get-data` with the following PHP code:

```
$itemData = $_POST["data"];
echo '<div id="content-json" style="display:none;">' . json_encode($itemData) . '</div>';
echo '<script>';
echo 'var json = document.getElementById("content-json").innerHTML;';
echo 'var data = JSON.parse(json);';
echo 'window.opener.returnCallback(data);';
echo 'window.close();';
echo "</script>';
```

The `returnCallback` function is on the same page (main window) as the button opening the new window:

```
function returnCallback(data)
{
    // Set page's content with data
    // ...
}
```

So basically we open a new window to other site, user does action, the new window redirects back to my site with POST data, gives the data to the main window as JS object and then closes the new window.

Now the problem is that the PHP session id gets regenerated when the new window is redirected back to my site. I have confirmed this with typing `document.cookie` into the main window's console.

Before clicking the button to open the new window and before clicking the button on the new window to redirect back to my site:

```
PHPSESSID=random12345
```

After redirecting back to my site and the new window closes:

```
PHPSESSID=random67890
```

What is even more interesting is that this doesn't happen every time and not with every user. It sometimes happens on one day on one browser with one user and then some other day/time it doesn't.

The only thing I can come up is if the domain changes between `www.example.com` and `example.com` but it's always `https://www.example.com`.

Anyone know any reason why this would happen?

Comment: Not an answer, just a suggestion... `echo 'var data = ' . json_encode($itemData) . ';';` is a whole lot simpler than what you've got going on there

Comment: I strongly suggest creating a unique [session name](https://www.php.net/manual/function.session-name.php) for your app. So many things use the default `PHPSESSID` that it's very easy to run into conflicts

Comment: @Phil The div mess was so I didn't need to escape json quotes/doublequotes inside the js code. I'll try changing the session name, although I don't think it's the problem here. The third party website has a unique session name.

Comment: `json_encode()` produces a string that can be used as a valid JavaScript data structure

Comment: Use your browser's _Network_ console to monitor which response is issuing the new session id (look for `Set-Cookie` headers). Look at the request for that response. Does it have a `Cookie` header with the old session ID? If so, then something in your code is replacing the old value, probably via `session_regenerate_id()`

Comment: I guess this could be an issue with 3rd-party cookie blocking - and what exactly different browsers/extensions might consider 3rd-party in such a scenario? (With your own site being considered the 3rd party here, when stuff is happening under the other domain.) Instead of doing `window.open("")`, I would try and open a page from your own site in the popup first, and then have that make the API request and redirect itself to the other domain - and see if that helps with retention of the session cookie.

Comment: @Phil Had to wait for an user to test it out but yes, that's exactly what is happening. The request back to my site has Set-Cookie header which changes the cookie. I don't have any session regenerate code anywhere in my code base and the only place where it is destroyed/unset is in logout script elsewhere.

Comment: @CBroe Tried that as well, unfortunately no luck.

Comment: Hi @bloodleh , Have you got any solution for this ?

Comment: @RathileshC Yes! I asked this same/similar question just a while ago, didn't even realize/remember that I had asked it previously (without a solution) almost a year ago haha :). The problem was that the cookies had attribute `samesite=lax`. Changing it to `samesite=none; secure` fixed it. https://stackoverflow.com/q/68478133/2219407 and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite#none for more info!